# Regex to extract name from list

Tags: python, regex, database, list, python-3.x

I am working with a text file (620KB) that has a list of ID#s followed by full names separated by a comma. 
The working regex I've used for this is

```
^([A-Z]{3}\d+)\s+([^,\s]+)
```

I want to also capture the first name and middle initial (space delimiter between first and MI).
I tried this by doing:

```
^([A-Z]{3}\d+)\s+([^,\s]+([\D])+)
```

Which works, but I want to remove the new line break that is generated on the output file (I will be importing the two output files into a database (possibly Access) and I don't want to capture the new line breaks, also if there is a better way of writing the regex?

Full code:

```
import re

source = open('source.txt')
ticket_list = open('ticket_list.txt', 'w')
id_list = open('id_list.txt', 'w')

for lines in source:
    m = re.search('^([A-Z]{3}\d+)\s+([^\s]+([\D+])+)', lines)
    if m:
        x = m.group()
        print('Ticket: ' + x)
        ticket_list.write(x + "\n")
ticket_list = open('First.txt', 'r')
for lines in ticket_list:
    y = re.search('^(\d+)\s+([^\s]+([\D+])+)', lines)
    if y:
        z = y.group()
        print ('ID: ' + z)
        id_list.write(z + "\n")
source.close()
ticket_list.close()
id_list.close()
```

Sample Data:
    Source:

```
ABC1000033830 SMITH, Z 
100000012 Davis, Franl R 
200000655 Gest, Baalio 
DEF4528942681 PACO, BETH 
300000233 Theo, David Alex 
400000012 Torres, Francisco B. 
ABC1200045682 Mo, AHMED 
DEF1000006753 LUGO, G TO 
ABC1200123123 de la Rosa, Maria E.
```

Comment: Upload some input data from the file and desired output.

Comment: Have you considered a second or alternative capture group regex for specifically the first name and middle initial? Also, this question would be easier to answer if you provided test data to use. I suspect using an alternative capture group will work, though.

Comment: if your source file is comma separated, why not use the csv module. then just append the 2nd column to your list of names. Seems way simpler, imho.

Comment: Not everyone's name is written the same, even when using an initial. (In-)Famous examples: L. Ron Hubbard, F. Scott Fitzgerald, M. Night Shyamalan, L. Sprague de Camp.

Comment: So I've uploaded a sample source file. I've noticed when importing data into MS ACCESS and Excel, two problems: the new line break becomes a record or row respectively (but that is trivial thing to remove) and some names fill up to 6 fields/columns (which is a problem, last names like 'de la rosa' take up 3 columns/fields without taking into account the first and middle initial. I'm not sure if I should rewrite the script or clean up the data in excel. @Jongware

Comment: @LuisFelipe, is the sample data you provided in the format which your regex is supposed to search through? I suspect not, as your pattern explicitly searches the beginning of a new line. Please make sure your source sample is in the same format. This is vital for the sake of pattern accuracy.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck The format is the same. I've only changed the ID's and Names for privacy. But this is the same format in which the source.txt is. Does this mean the regex is incorrectly written?

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, in your sample data you have sequences that are only numeric, and contain no letters. Is this intended? If so, are these supposed to be captured as well? In its current state, that pattern won't work on all your sample data.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck the id sequence with a mix of 3 character codes and 9 digit id are tickets, the records with only 9 digit sequence are ID's. I separated the Tickets and IDs into two separate textfiles which I want to later manipulate in a DB or excel to find matches. People with tickets with their ID, this is done by relating the last and first name. which is why it is important for me to capture the names correctly.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck The regex worked correctly as I was able to get the data into the two separate files correctly. The trouble is once I import the data into Access and Excel

Comment: I'm showing that your pattern is matching more than what you're trying to get, so I'd say that it's not just a matter of dealing with Excel and Access, at this point. Eg, after the **Mo, AHMED** string ends, **DEF** is also matched.

Comment: It looks like all your pattern needed was a positive lookahead, in that case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what kind of linebreak you're dealing with, a simple positive lookahead may remedy your pattern capturing the linebreak in the result. This was generated by RegexBuddy 4.2.0, and worked with all your test data.

```
if re.search(r"^([A-Z]{3}\d+)\s+([^,\s]+([\D])+)(?=$)", subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Basically, the positive lookahead makes sure that there is a linebreak (in this case, end of line) character directly after the pattern ends. It will match, but not capture the actual end of line.